# how to refresh page after user logout with 'wp_logout_url'?

Tags: javascript, login, logout

I have written a plugin for my own site where I have an issue like "after user login to the site if he logout then again if he clicks on browser back button then the previous page showing again instead of login page". Iam trying the below code but it doesn't work.

```
<script>
   window.onhashchange = function() {
     <?php if( ! is_user_logged_in()) { $this->tewa_login(); } ?>
   }
<script>
```

My logout code is below:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  $data .= '<li><a class="add-new" href="'. wp_logout_url() .'" class="btn btn-primary" >'.$this->icon_sign_out.' Logout</a></li>';
}
```

Can the below code works or not?

```
function my_redirect(){
  <script>
     location.reload();
  </script>
 exit();
}
add_filter('wp_logout','my_redirect');
```

I think this issue totally browser issue not belongs to server. I think just a page refresh that does the trick. I was using 'wp_logout_url' for user logout. how to do it can anyone plz tell me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take time to edit your post for clarity of expression. As it stands, it is not clear what the challenge is, what you are trying to achieve, WordPress version, edited file and or location of custom code, any eventual error, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [wp_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) after logout. There's an example of how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870082/log-out-wordpress-and-redirect-to-different-url).

```
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'auto_redirect_external_after_logout');
function auto_redirect_external_after_logout(){
  wp_redirect( 'http://redirect-url' );
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Could you please tell me where to write that 'wp_redirect'? I think may in theme functions.php file as a hook.

Comment: Just a link is not very good answer; could you please elaborate a practical answer with sample code and explain how it fix the problem of the question?

Comment: I just have edited it.

Comment: @PrasadPatel Add the code in your functions.php and it should work fine. Just replace the "http://redirect-url" with your URL where you want to redirect after logout.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to refresh (and not redirect to a different page) use 'get_permalink()'

it's in the docs...

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>">Logout</a>
```